# “Tell me yourself” vs “tell me about yourself”

Tags: transitivity

> Tell me yourself.

vs

> Tell me about yourself.

Tell is a transitive verb and transitive verb needs a direct object. Here “me” is the indirect object and “yourself” is the direct object. I don't understand why “about” comes before an direct object (yourself).

Answer (score 2):

The meaning of "Tell me about yourself" is "describe yourself". The person does not respond by "telling himself or herself"  a person is not a thing that can be told. Instead the response is to tell some items of description, that is some items **about** the person.

Similarly one does not say "Tell me New York". Rather, one says "Tell me about New York." One uses the form "Tell me X" **only** when X is i thing that can be told, such as "a story". Otherwise, one uses "Tell me about X" no matter what X is. That is just how English handles this -- "Tell me about X." means "describe X.", while "Tell me X" is meaningless unless X is an account in words:

> - Tell me what happened.
> - Tell me the plot.
> - Tell me about the movie.
> - Tell me what she said.

Comment: "_Tell me yourself_" is also valid. It is the suggestion or command "_**You** tell me about X rather than someone else._"